# illegal action in notepad++

Tags: c++, notepad++

I just started to teach myself C++ and i'm trying to run a simple code on notepad ++ and when it pops up it says the NTVDM CPU has encountered and illegal instruction. could it be a problem with my code? or is it something else. just incase it is my code this is the simple code:

```
// Your Name - Project Title - Date - (Whatever Else-Optional)
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main (void){

    cout << "Hello World!";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: How are you compiling the code?  Are you using NppExecute?

Comment: Code is okey. It's look like you have a problem with compiler. Are you useing GCC, GNU compiler?

Comment: As a side note: avoid `using namespace std;`, better omit it and write `std::cout << "...";` instead.

Comment: Oh, sorry but where do i find the compilers?

Comment: http://gcc.gnu.org/ <- GCC, GNU compiler.  But on the begining I recomend you to download for example DEV CPP - IDE for C/C++.

Answer (score 0):

General advice is: Ensure that you are able to compile your code using the command line (1) using plain shell command (I mean without Notepad++) AND (2) your compile batch runs from any folder from where you launch it.  If you get your compile batch working, then adapt it for Notepad++ and call it from there.

If you find you have a compile problem (independent of N++ as I shown above), please re-classify your StackOverflow question also possibly with different tags so correct people can find it.